# Can't configure Qt on windows

Tags: qt, configure

I have source code folder of Qt 5.1.0 and also 4.8.4. The thing is that when I put command:
configure -static -release -no-exeptions the text of help screen only flashes and nothing else happens. What's the problem?

Please, help me ASAP.

Comment: If it opens the help screen then you typed some parameter wrong. I hope you are running the configure from the command prompt. And if this is visual studio make sure you are using the correct visual studio command prompt for your compiler and 32/ 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Qt 5.1 is released as an SDK.  Additionally, you can install and use the 4.8.4 library -  which I currently use.  Is there a reason you need to build from source?

Comment: The OP seems to want to build qt statically which is not included in the free downloads. I warn the OP that there are restrictions on using static Qt in commercial applications unless you get the commercial version of Qt.

Comment: The only build not free are the commercial libraries.  Yes you're correct concerning the LGPL but the SDK is still free to download.